# Social network wall posting logic not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

With the screenshot and the code below I am trying to get the 'Delete Button' to only show to the owner of the wall post. I am logged in as Michael Grigsby and as you can tell from the screenshot that the first wall post is hiding the 'Delete Button' but the rest are showing even when it comes to the Mike Wyatt post which I should not have ownership of.

I cannot figure out why this is being caused. I have two possibilities; either I have to loop through the wall posts in jQuery, or my SQL statement is not written right. Any ideas as to why this is acting this way?

[image]

PHP and jQuery Code:

```
<?php   $this->load->helper('date');
        $userid = $this->session->userdata('userid');
        $query  = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM churchMembers WHERE cMuserId = '{$userid}'");
        $row = $query->row();
        if ($query->num_rows() != 0) {
        $membersChurchId = $row->cMchurchId;
        $query2 = $this->db->query("SELECT wp.idwallPosts, wp.entryData, wp.entryCreationDateTime, u.firstname, u.lastname, u.userid, u.defaultImgURI FROM users u
                                   INNER JOIN wallPosts wp ON wp.postingUserid = u.userid
                                   WHERE wp.wpChurchId = '{$membersChurchId}' ORDER BY wp.idwallPosts DESC LIMIT 200");
foreach ($query2->result() as $row) { ?>
    <?php // the following php is the bootstrapper for the wall
        if ($userid != $row->userid) { ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#delPost").remove();
                });
            </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm looking at this:

```
$("#delPost").remove();
```

...and thinking that you probably have `id="delPost"` on every item. A common misunderstanding about `id` attributes is that you can re-use them, but you can't. There can only be one element per page with `id="delPost"` ([validating](http://validator.w3.org/) your HTML would reveal the error).

Anyways, your script is only reading the first one, as demonstrated by [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pLk7b/).  Each id must be unique, you may want to switch to `class` instead and rethink your logic, but that doesn't make too much sense anyways because in that loop, as soon as one element is hidden they *all* would be because your selector is not very specific (applies to *every* element that matches your selector, looping/repeating that script is redundant).

There are many ways to approach this but here's what I suggest: Instead of hiding or removing them with javascript, just don't output them at all with your PHP code.

Comment: Yeah i totally forgot about using class. I just recently learned that too. and what i was thinking moreso XSS. All somebody would have to do is is replace the .hide() or .remove() with .show() and they'd be set. So in my SQL and Ci code, how would I go about hiding them

Comment: Try my comment on the other answer if you must use javascript for hiding the links. Aside, I don't think this has anything to do with XSS... This **really** should be done on the server side primarily if you want to avoid unauthorized actions. Anyone can link/post to your delete URL with whatever params they want. Javascript is not a final answer to this issue of security. Don't forget it can be disabled entirely by the user.

Comment: @MichaelGrigsby - "removing" the elements isn't any better; your server-side code needs to be checking the logged-in user ID to the comment before deleting. XSS can be checked to a degree with http-only cookies and/or an action ID with a timeout (sent http-only too), but what you describe doesn't seem like XSS or CSRF per se.

Comment: Okay. I just need to get something for right now. I'll tinker with it when i have more time down the road to make it more secure. let me try what you've suggested so far. thanks for your help btw

Comment: I'd strongly advise you stop regarding security as an afterthought.

Comment: Okay. well do you think you could help me with getting to work in my PHP? My mind isn't as sharp as it use to be. I can't figure out how to get it to work in the php

Comment: I have to go in a minute (actually right now), but basically if the current user's id matches the post author's id, display the delete link, otherwise don't. Then in your delete function, same thing: deny the action if the user's id doesn't match the post author's id. One more thing: you should use POST for deletes. You can style the submit button like a link or if you find that difficult, replace it with an anchor using js and do an AJAX delete (or both). Wish I could stick around and help more but I have band practice, sorry.

Comment: Oh wow I just remembered how to do it. If, echo. else exit. I can't believe I forgot that logic. thanks man

Answer (score 3):

`#delPost` implies that you are using `id="delPost"`. HTML, however, requires that IDs be unique. You probably want to use a `class="delPost"` and `.delPost` instead.

Comment: How would a class name help in this context? Wouldn't that be redundant? The code is in a loop and the same selector is used over and over. I realize how fundamentally ugly that is but I'm not entirely certain if just swapping id for class would make any difference.

Comment: @WesleyMurch - I think the OP wants to "hide" (remove) all of the `Delete` links. So a class seems entirely reasonable, unless I'm not getting something here. Note, though, it wouldn't need to be added more than once (if that's what you mean).

Comment: I think something like adding `data-author-id="{AUTHOR_ID}"` to each post/link, then (outside the loop), using something like `$('.delPost:not([data-author-id="{$userid}"])').remove()` might work. It's hard to properly band-aid that which is severely broken.